# Mocking YUI function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, yui, mockito

I have `signup.js`, which contains one function name `demo()`. This function call another YUI library function with arguments:

```
Y.io('mywrongserver',callbackfunction);
```

I have to test this function but I want to make call to right server

```
Y.io('myrightserver',callbackfunction);
```

How is it possible? I do not want to change any code in `signup.js` as it is done by developer.

Can we make use of Mocking?

Code would be like this:

**signup.js**

```
demo : function(){
    alert('i am inside demo');
    // Some other stuff
    callback = {
        on :{
            success:function(x,o){
                // Some stuff here
            }
        }
    }
    // Now call to wrong server
    Y.io("mywrongserver", callback);
```

**test.js**

```
// Using JSMOCKITO APIs for YUI
testDemo = function(){
    // Need to test demo function in signup.js But such that Y.io call to right server 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I have voted to re-open this.  The close reason given doesn't seem to be applicable.  This isn't a problem with code - it's a question about whether mocking can be used to test this.  The answer would seem to be YES - this is what mocking is for.  But I haven't posted an answer because I don't know if there's a mocking library that would deal with this particular case.  Trying out jsmockito seems to be the obvious thing to do, but I don't have time.  Whether or not this can be tested with jsmockito seems to me to be a perfectly valid question.

Comment: The answer is indeed "yes". I haven't used jsmockto, but I can answer it it in general terms. Basically, you overwrite `Y.io` with your own function that tests whether `Y.io`was passed the correct arguments. Please reopen the question.

Comment: @DavidWallace - information on the topic of mock objects and how to create them can be found in the YUI docs or by using Google. If "yes" is the answer to this question, not only will others figure this out themselves using Google or YUI/JSMockito, it is also not a question fit for this format. Thus off topic.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange  : Well, First of all I am not asking how to mock objects and other thing. I was not sure whether for case given above, can i use mocking and if you are saying this can be found using google . THEN Everything can be found using google. There is no use of stackoverflow.com at all. :) .. don't mine just my personal opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answer is indeed "yes". I haven't used jsmockto, but I can answer it it in general terms. Basically, you overwrite Y.io with your own function that tests whether Y.io was passed the correct arguments.